# How to set default value in formControl in angular 5

Tags: angular

If there is no data in the table, I am getting undefined from service but I want to display default value in formControl in that case. if data is there then working fine...Please help me and suggest what I need to do.

Comment: You're using subject or behavior subject to watch for data change?

Comment: @AdrianSawicki yes I am using behavior subject

Comment: You can pass default value to it or just as people wrote below you can add it to your FormBuilder

Answer (score 28):

When you create the group and controls inside it, you can also initialize them.

*`fb` is the `FormBuilder`*

```
fb.group({
   yourControl: [0, Validators.required] // '0' is the default value
});
```

Comment: Shouldn't `Validators` be wrapped in another one array?

Comment: If you use only one - in that case no, if you have multiple validators - you need to put into another array like `[0, [Vaidators.required, Validators.email]]`.

Comment: Thanks for clarification

Comment: From Angular 6, I think you need to use `Validators.compose([...])` or you get validation issues (or it's just me, but you never know). And form controls aren't always form groups, you should include the creation of a form control in your answer (`this.control = new FormControl('default value')`)

Comment: I absolutely love this kind of answers. Short, precise and accurate. Thank you.

Comment: Now deprecated.

Answer (score 4):

You can try with default value in form control.

```
myForm: FormGroup;
ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
        name: ["test", [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(30)]],
        address: this.fb.group({
            pin: ["123456", Validators.required]
        })
    });
}
```

Comment: Now deprecated.

Comment: @MartinEckleben What are they deprecated in favour of?

Comment: @Qasim They changed the signature of the group() method. Too unreadable to post code here - better look it up yourself https://angular.io/api/forms/FormBuilder

Answer (score 1):

Using FormControl constructor:

```
myFormGroup = new FormGroup({
    mycontrol: new FormControl('myDefaultValue'),
});
```

doc source: [Angular.io - Initializing Form Controls](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl#initializing-form-controls)