# how to show default value in angular forms with validation?

Tags: angular

I am having some difficulty with this form.

I am trying to make a form which can validate and also display a default value at the start.
The problems I am facing:

1. Once I add in the line "formControlName"=price, "formControlName"=description, "formControlName"=name, the value is no longer displayed on the screen.

Before adding the line "formControlName" [Values can appear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nocbe.png)

After adding the line "form ControlName" [Has Validation, but even after form is valid cannot get alert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SxWK3.png)

2. Cannot validate form properly, when I remove the value I set in the html file, and enter a new value. The form does not trigger an alert dialogue as expected.

Code (HTML)

```
<div class="container">
  <h2>Edit Product Details</h2>


  <form [formGroup]="updateProductForm" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
    <label for="pname">Product Name:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="pname" name="pname" value={{products.name}}><br>
    <!-- error lies here -->
    <div class="error-list" *ngIf="fc.pname.errors && isSubmitted">
      <div *ngIf="fc.pname.errors.required">Should not be empty</div>


    </div>
    <label for="price">Unit Price:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="price" name="price" value={{products.price}}><br>
    <!-- error lies here -->
    <div class="error-list" *ngIf="fc.price.errors && isSubmitted">
      <div *ngIf="fc.price.errors.required">Should not be empty</div>


    </div>

    <label for="price">Product Description:</label><br>
    <textarea type="text" style="overflow: scroll; height: 200px; width: 500px;" value={{products.description}}
      id="description" name="description"> </textarea><br>
    <div class="error-list" *ngIf="fc.description.errors && isSubmitted">
      <div *ngIf="fc.description.errors.required">Should not be empty</div>


    </div>
    <label for="img">Change Display Image:</label><br>
    <input type="file" id="img" name="img" accept="image/*"><br><br>
    <button type="submit">Update Product Details</button>
    <button style="margin-left: 10px;">Delete Product</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Code(type-script)

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { CartService } from '../cart.service';
import { FavService } from '../fav.service';
import { products } from '../models/products';
import { ProductsService } from '../products.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-update-delete-product',
  templateUrl: './update-delete-product.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./update-delete-product.component.css']
})
export class UpdateDeleteProductComponent implements OnInit {
  updateProductForm!: FormGroup;
  isSubmitted = false;
  products!: products;
  constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, private productService: ProductsService,
    private cartService: CartService, private router: Router, private formbuilder: FormBuilder) {
    activatedRoute.params.subscribe((params) => {
      if (params.id)
        this.products = productService.getProductsById(params.id)
    }
    )
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.updateProductForm = this.formbuilder.group({
      pname: ['', [Validators.required]],
      price: ['', Validators.required],
      description: ['', Validators.required]

    });
  }
  get fc() {
    return this.updateProductForm.controls;
  }
  submit() {
    this.isSubmitted = true;
    if (this.updateProductForm.valid) return alert(`You have succefully updated the form!`)
    // alert (`email: ${this.fc.email.value},
    // password: ${this.fc.password.value}`)
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Answer

> 1. Once I add in the line "formControlName"=price,
>    "formControlName"=description, "formControlName"=name, the value is no
>    longer displayed on the screen.

Instead of this

```
<input type="text" id="pname" name="pname" value={{products.name}}>
```

**do this** as I wrote for all inputs with the correct name

```
<input type="text" id="pname" formControlName="pname">
```

Should work properly

> 2. Cannot validate form properly, when I remove the value I set in the
>    html file, and enter a new value. The form does not trigger an alert
>    dialogue as expected.

This is due to the fact that, because **you did not associate each input to the correct control** with the formControlName property, form cannot find the data it expects and because of that **it does not perform validation**

After fixing the first point, validation should also work fine

See the [official documentation](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#grouping-form-controls) for more informations, it is very clear and helpful

---

### Additional Tips

**To set the default values** in the various controls, instead of doing this

```
<input type="text" id="pname" formControlName="pname" value={{products.name}}>
```

**remove value property** and **do this**

```
 this.formbuilder.group({
  pname: [products.name, Validators.required], // first parameter represents the default value
  price: [products.price, Validators.required],
  description: [products.description, Validators.required],
});
```

in your case, you retrieve the product data in the `constructor()` via the productService so when `onInit()` is called you should already have the data in `products`

For more information about that, look this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51152564/how-to-set-default-value-in-formcontrol-in-angular-5)

---

I hope I was helpful, let me know how it goes! :)